# Dynamic estimation of required sample size in R

Tags: r, estimation, sample-size

I have a prospective study  with no data about estimated results, that could be used to get required sample size. Data looks like this:

```
caseID;groupID;value,result
1;1;12.3;0
2;1;15.6;1
3;2;11.3;0
4;2;13.4;1
...
```

Is it possible to determine how much observations should be made to complete the study after adding new portion of data?

I need both descriptive statistics ( % of cases have sign X, *result* in example ) and comparative (2-4 groups compared by continuous variable,*value* in example). Probability of type I  error ($\alpha$) is 10%    and type II ($\beta$) - 5% (*for example*) Statistical significance and power - 0,9 and 0,95. The best solution is to have a grid like this for making desision to stop or continue the study:

```
a;b;n
5;5;30
10;5;28
5;10;29
...
```

Where a is $\alpha$ , b is $\beta$ and n is the size of sample required for study with this $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (Type I and type 2 error probability).
My data is imported to R. Is it possible to perform some calculations to get?:

1. Number observations required to complete study
2. Required number of observations for each group

So I need to estimate sample size based on actual data to know it is time to finish the study.

The question is: 
**How to do this in R, if it is possible?**

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: you need to give more information. How much data have you collected? What kind of data is it? Are you aiming for a statistical power threshold?

Comment: @richiemorrisroe The number of observations is the data I need. Updated the question with example data set and information on possible error probability.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test might have some helpful references.